# Failure to clone risc-v tools (failure with newlib-cygwin.git)

Tags: git, github, cygwin, riscv, newlib

I have been attempting to clone the risc-v GNU toolchain on Linux but failing.

On:

```
 git clone --recursive https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain
```

I get (fragment):

```
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'riscv-glibc': checked out '7395b0964db9cc4dd544926414960e9a16842180'
Cloning into 'riscv-newlib'...
fatal: unable to connect to sourceware.org:
sourceware.org[0: 8.43.85.97]: errno=Connection refused
sourceware.org[1: 2620:52:3:1:0:246e:9693:128c]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

I thought this might be a transient network problem but it has persisted for days now.

Subsequently trying:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Similarly fails:

```
Cloning into 'riscv-newlib'...
fatal: unable to connect to sourceware.org:
sourceware.org[0: 8.43.85.97]: errno=Connection refused
sourceware.org[1: 2620:52:3:1:0:246e:9693:128c]: errno=Network is unreachable

fatal: clone of 'git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git' into submodule path 'riscv-newlib' failed
```

I have tried this:

```
 git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com
```

But it makes no difference.

Anyone know of a way round this?

Comment: Does `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git` work for you?

Comment: On further investigation I can see there appears to be a failing commit that changed the remote for the submodule. I have reversed that but it's still trying the failing URL - how can I force it to use the updated (corrected) URL?

Comment: No - the clone of the sourceware repo fails

Comment: Hmm, it's working for me. Can you access http://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git?

Comment: yes, that works - but the CI stuff on the risc-v repo indicates that the sourceware git is failing for their CI server also.

Comment: It's possible that git protocol is forbidden in your network. Try using http: `git clone https://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git`

Comment: I have just axed my download and restarted it after editing the .gitmodules file to remove the failing update - hopefully that will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo's CI tools report that the most recent patch is failing. so reversing that fixed this problem for me.

Specifically:

```
git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain
```

(ie don't start recursion at this point)

```
cd riscv-gnu-toolchain
```

Edit .gitmodules to **reverse** this:

```
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
    url = ../riscv-dejagnu.git
[submodule "riscv-newlib"]
    path = riscv-newlib
   -  url = ../riscv-newlib.git
   +  url = git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git
[submodule "riscv-gdb"]
    path = riscv-gdb
    url = ../riscv-binutils-gdb.git
```

Then:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```